# tag <a> not clickable on relatively positioned block

Tags: html, css

I have a little piece code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Asia Maldivas</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#">TEST OUTER RELATIVE</a>
        <div class="bg">
           <a href="#">TEST</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
.bg {
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(18,138,167,0.95) 30px,rgba(62,195,209,0.95) 7%,rgba(12,115,160,1) 100%);
    z-index: -1;
}

a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Now I have a link which is not clickable and I don't understand why.

Comment: Changing the z-index works.  I'm assuming making it -1 puts it behind something, which is making it unreachable - albeit whatever it's behind is invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by the z-index: -1; If you remove that, it will be clickable.

Answer (score 1):

As Dan said, you need to remove `z-index: -1` from the `.bg`. Here is live example:

https://jsfiddle.net/smmmrw7g/

It seems that z-index have some inheritance one from another.